# Max value - Mantissa calculation clarification?

Tags: education, computational-mathematics, floating-point

I've been reading this [*article about floating point representation*](http://www.dspguide.com/ch4/3.htm)

floating point representation is :

[image]

Where mantissa is :

[image]

All understood.

But they also say :

[image]

How did they get to `2^(-23)` ?

in the mantissa there are 23 bits which referes to `1.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

(23 x's)

so what is the max value for 23 bits ?

it's `2^(23)-1`

Since `x's` it's location is on the right side so `2^(-22)` and we need to add the `1.`

So it should  be `2^0 + 2^(-23)-1`

How did they get to `2^(-23)` ?

## edit :

found the answer.

let's look at 3 bit mantissa for example :

1.111 will be the max

so it will be 1111.0 *2^(-3)

what's the value in the left side ?  it's (2^4)-1

so let's do :

(2^4 - 1 )* 2^(-3)  ==> which is `2 - 2^(-3)`

Comment: The highest bit of the mantissa is implied and not stored, i.e. implicitly you have a 24-bit mantissa.

Comment: @gammatester I dont understand why the `2-__` ? can you elaborate more please ?

Comment: @gammatester read my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The largest mantissa consists of 23 bits 1: 
$$11111111111111111111111 = 2^{23}-1.$$ 
With the implied bit convention this gives for the *real maximum Mantissa* $M_m$
$$M_m=1.11111111111111111111111 = 1+(2^{23}-1)2^{-23} = 1+1 -2^{-23} = 2-2^{-23}$$
And therefore the largest number is 
$$M_m \times 2^{254-127}= (2-2^{-23})\times 2^{127} = 2^{128}-2^{104}\\
=340282346638528859811704183484516925440 \approx 3.40282\times 10^{38}$$

Comment: Exactly like my edit. 1 more question please. how did they calc that it's equal to `6.8 × 10^38` ?

Comment: p.s. you one line before last has an error : it's `x 2^(128)` and not `2^127`. becuase `(2^8)-1=255  =>  255-127 = 128`

Comment: Yes, I was computing for IEEE and there the $254-127$ is correct. On the page 
they extended the resulting exponent range and note: "The IEEE standard reduces this range slightly to free bit patterns", in IEEE these exponents 255 are used for **Inf** and **NaN**. In their Eq. 4.1 $E-127$ they substitute $E=255$ and get a factor 2.

Comment: Now i'm really confused.where the `254−127` came from?

Comment: There are 8 bits for the exponent. The exponent is stored in **biased** form to avoid storing an exponent sign,  i.e. stored exponent = true exponent + 127. This is the case for both formats (IEEE and your page, see Eq.4.1). The difference is that IEEE does not use the biased exponent 255 for normal numbers but for **Inf** and **NaN** (and the maximum biased exponent for normal IEEEs is therefore 254).

Comment: Sorry to re-ask . but - I hve a question about the 254. with 8 bits  - the max value is 256-1=>255.  Now  , [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponent_bias) says that 0 and 255 are reserved. so  , 255-2(specials)=255-2=253. where is the 254 comes from ?

Comment: Yes, there are two special exponent values in IEEE (namely those 255 and 0), but 254 is still the largest exponent for normalized numbers.

Comment: No chat, but what is the problem? It is IMO quite clear and even Wiki says: *For a single-precision number, an exponent in the range −126 .. +127 is biased by adding 127 to get a value in the range 1 .. 254 (0 and 255 have special meanings).* And your calculation 255-2 has a small error: There are **256** bit patters (0..255), two are reserved (0 and 255), remaining are 254 usable biased exponents: 1..254.

Comment: Except the reserved places , which I understand , ( and i did got it wrong - with the 254 , thank you for correcting me) , what was their problem that they decided to use bias ? was it to prevent using 2's complement ?

Comment: Quote from Goldberg, What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About
Floating-Point Arithmetic: _An advantage of biased representation is that nonnegative flouting-point numbers can be treated as integers for comparison purposes._

Comment: Well , didnt know who's Goldberg is , now I know and i'm certainly going to print and read this article. thank you very much for your knowledge , help and patience. p.s. do you write this styled math syntax symbols automatically from your head? or is there a tool ?

Comment: See the first ref at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Further_reading,
or as a pdf from http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.22.6768. Regarding math style: I normally put it in the answer box where the preview is available.

Comment: Hi. I want to continue the result of `2^(128)-2^(104)` into this pattern : `y*x^(m)`  - and I see you got this by actual calculating. but how can I do it without calculating the large number ?  I just want the result `3.4*10^38` is there anyway yo to get this number( or close enough) without calculating it ?

Comment: $M_m$ is obviously close to $2^{128}.$  To get a decimal approximation you may compute with logarithms:
$$\log_{10}M_m=\log_{10}2^{128}=128\log_{10}(2) \approx 128\times0.30103=38.53184$$
and therefore
$$M_n=10^{\log_{10}M_m}\approx 10^{38.53184}=10^{0.53184}\times  10^{38} \approx 3.4028\times 10^{38}$$

Comment: huh??? how does `Mm` is close to `2^128` ? Mm is `1.11111111111111111111111` ....no ?

Comment: Right you are! Kind of blackout, justed needed a name for $2^{128}-2^{104}.\,$ Replace $M_m$ with `MaxSingle` or so. But the calculation is OK.